# Program for generating the coefficients of the nth cyclotomic polynomial

Tags: algorithms, cyclotomic-polynomials

Is there a program that generates the coefficients of the nth cyclotomic polynomial?

Comment: There must be, though I don't know of one specifically.  Computing the $n$th cyclotomic polynomial is a highly recursive procedure, since it is $x^n-1$ divided by the product of all $d$th cyclotomic polynomials where $d$ is a proper divisor of $n$.  Try Maple, Mathematica, GAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The software [pari/gp](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) which is free and has many functions relevant to algebraic number theory has a built-in function "polcyclo" which returns the whole of the $n$th cyclotomic polynomial.

Thus the command:

```
? polcyclo(10)
```

Returns the answer:

```
x^4 - x^3 + x^2 - x + 1
```

Does that help?